# Automatically closing browser in kiosk mode after a timeout of some minutes or user inactivity

Tags: command-line-arguments, chromium, kiosk-mode, microsoft-edge-chromium

Operating System: Linux TLXOS
Available Browsers: Chromium and Microsoft Edge

**I am trying to set up a terminal where my my colleagues can log in and browse in our intranet. The goal is to get a browser that opens in kiosk mode and closes itself if the user has not made any entries for a while.**

Currently the browser successfully starts in kiosk and incognito mode and it opens our startpage. So far so good, but what I am missing is something like a timeout that just closes the browser after a certain amount of time, because this terminal shall be placed in a public area.

Actually I have to ways to edit the Command Line Args:

1. directly on the Intel Nuc in the browser properties
2. remotly in the TMS Management Software of TLXOS (opens the browser after it gets closed)

Besides Chromium I also tried Microsoft Edge, because I thought I had found a well solution (that was just for Edge), but in the end the output is the same, I still miss a timeout that closes the browser. These are my current Command Arguments/Switches:

(Chromium)
*usr/bin/chromium --incognito --kiosk https://stackoverflow.com --user-response-timeout=1*

(Microsoft Edge)
*usr/bin/microsoft-edge --kiosk https://stackoverflow.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --kiosk-idle-timeout-minutes=1*

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a way for it to remain closed after the reset